# Drag and Drop a shape in Java awt applet

Tags: java, applet

I'm trying to create an awt applet in which the user can drag around a rectangle that has been drawn on the applet. I can't figure out why the rectangle in my applet only drags diagonally and in the positive x direction, I can't move it up or down or to the left, it only drags diagonally to the right. Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my logic ?

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DragRectangle extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener {

  boolean clicked_in_rectangle = false;

  int rectangleX, rectangleY, mouseX, mouseY;
  int rectangle_width = 80, rectangle_height = 50;

  public void init() {
    rectangleX = 0;
    rectangleY = 0;
    mouseX = 0;
    mouseY = 0;
    addMouseMotionListener(this);

  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.drawRect(rectangleX, rectangleY, rectangle_width, rectangle_height);
      if(clicked_in_rectangle) {
        rectangleX = mouseX;
        rectangleY = mouseY;
        g.drawRect(rectangleX, rectangleY, rectangle_width,   rectangle_height);
      }

  }

  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();

    clicked_in_rectangle = mouseX > rectangleX && mouseY > rectangleY &&
                           mouseX < rectangleX + rectangle_width && mouseY < rectangleY + rectangle_height;

    repaint();
  }

  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're setting the rectangle's position to the mouse's pointer position and when you try to drag the rectangle up or to the left, the pointer will be outside of the rectangle's bounds and `clicked_in_rectangle` will be `false`.

You can try this:

```
if (clicked_in_rectangle) {
    rectangleX = mouseX - 3;
    rectangleY = mouseY - 3;
    g.drawRect(rectangleX, rectangleY, rectangle_width, rectangle_height);
}
```

But this is still not an ideal solution, it stops working if you try to drag the rectangle (up or to the left) quickly, that's because the `rectangleX` and `rectangleY` don't get a chance to be updated to the new position.

If you want something more reliable, you can do this:

```
public class DragRectangle extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

boolean clicked_in_rectangle = false, dragStarted = false;

int x, y, px, py;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 80, 50);

public void init() {
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (clicked_in_rectangle) {
        int nx = rect.x + (x - px);
        int ny = rect.y + (y - py);

        Rectangle bounds = g.getClipBounds();
        boolean reset = false;
        if (nx + rect.width > bounds.width || nx < 0) {
            nx = rect.x;
            reset = true;
        }
        if (ny + rect.height > bounds.height || ny < 0) {
            ny = rect.y;
            reset = true;
        }
        if (reset) {
            px = 0;
            py = 0;
        } else {
            px = x;
            py = y;
        }

        rect = new Rectangle(nx, ny, rect.width, rect.height);
    }
    g.drawRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);

}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if (dragStarted) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        if (px == 0 && py == 0) {
            px = x;
            py = y;
        } else {
            clicked_in_rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1).intersects(rect);
            if (clicked_in_rectangle) {
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        dragStarted = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1).intersects(rect);
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        px = 0;
        py = 0;
    }
}

}
```

I may have made this more complicated then it has to be, in any case, the idea is to change the shape's position based on the difference between consecutive pointer coordinates instead of setting its position to the same position as the pointer.